# How to fetch the key in nested JSON File and add it to a Combo Box

Tags: c#, json, winforms, combobox

I watnt to read the property name from the nested JSON file and update it to the comboBox in the Windows form.this is how my JSON file is nested,

```
{
   "Configurations": {
      "Tr984": {
         "Operations": {
            "pressure": {
               "speed": 1000,
               "IpAddress": "*****",
               "TcpPort": ***,
               "UnitId": ****,
               and so on..
            },
            "Engage":{
               "Interval": 1000,
               "IpAddress": "****",
               "TcpPort": ***,
               "UnitId": ****,
               and so on..
            },
            "Volume": {
               "density": 1000,
               "IpAddress": "****",
               "Port": 8888,
               "
            }
         }
      }
   }
```

I want to access all the key names `Pressure` ,`Engage`,`Volume` and add it to the `comboBox1`,Dynamically.Currently I am using for each loops to reach the inner most key,value pairs and not able to fetch only the property as mentioned.Since I am a beginner to C# Coding Can you Please help me to solve the issue?

```
private void comboBox1_Click(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(@"**********"))
    {
        var json = r.ReadToEnd();
        var jobj = JObject.Parse(json);

        foreach (var item in jobj.Properties())

            foreach (var item2 in item.Value)

                foreach (var item3 in item2)

                    foreach (var item4 in item3)

                        foreach (var rawTags in item4)

                            foreach (var pair in rawTags)

                                foreach (var value in pair)
                                {
                                    string propName=Convert.ToString(value.Next);
                                    comboBox1.Items.Add(propName);  
                                }
    }
}
```

Comment: how about a recursive method?

Comment: I know its not a good practice to use many foreach loops like that,so Can you please suggest how to fetch the propety name as mentioned above?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to model a class around your json and deserialize it directly into this class.
For modelling a class around your json you can make use of a tool like [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/). This will give you this class structure:

```
public class Pressure
{
    public int speed { get; set; }
    public string IpAddress { get; set; }
    public int TcpPort { get; set; }
    public int UnitId { get; set; }
}

public class Engage
{
    public int Interval { get; set; }
    public string IpAddress { get; set; }
    public int TcpPort { get; set; }
    public int UnitId { get; set; }
}

public class Volume
{
    public int density { get; set; }
    public string IpAddress { get; set; }
    public int Port { get; set; }
}

public class Operations
{
    public Pressure pressure { get; set; }
    public Engage Engage { get; set; }
    public Volume Volume { get; set; }
}

public class Tr984
{
    public Operations Operations { get; set; }
}

public class Configurations
{
    public Tr984 Tr984 { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Configurations Configurations { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can use a framework like [Json.Net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to deserialize the given json:

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

And access the keys like this:

```
var pressure = obj.Operations.pressure
// and so on
```

---

If your json string is too big to model a class around it you can make use of Json.Net [dynamic features](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonDynamic.htm):

```
dynamic configurations = JArray.Parse(json);
dynamic pressure = configurations.Tr984.Operations.pressure;
var speed = pressure.speed;
// and so on
```

---

**Update**
If you do not know the json structure at compile time and you just want the key names beyond the `Operations` node, you can modify my example from above to achieve this.

Change the class structure so that instead of specific keys all children of `Operations` will be deserialized into a dictionary:

```
public class Tr984
{
    public Dictionary<string,object> Operations { get; set; }
}

public class Configurations
{
    public Tr984 Tr984 { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Configurations Configurations { get; set; }
}
```

Now after deserialization:

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

Every json key will be a key in the dictionary. To get them simply iterate over them:

```
foreach(var key in obj.Configurations.Tr984.Operations.Keys)
{
    comboBox1.Items.Add(key);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer I will try that my question is when the changes are made in JSON file that is added few more property value pairs like Pressure or engage or Volume,  These key names(like Pressure,Volume) should be automatically updated in the combo box of the form .So I need a suggestion to automatically take key names like pressure,Volume and any other key names added to JSON file so that no need to modify the code as it automatically updates the added key names to combo Box.Please can anybody help

Answer (score 0):

You can access it this way:

```
dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

var pressure = obj.Configurations.Tr984.Operations.pressure;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to querying on your `JObject` like

```
JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(json);

var result = jObject["Configurations"]["Tr984"]["Operations"].Children().Children().ToList().Select(x => x.ToObject<JObject>()).Properties().Select(y => new { Key = y.Name, Value = y.Value });

foreach (var i in result)
{
    //comboBox1.Items.Add(i.Value);  
    Console.WriteLine(i.Key + ": " + i.Value);
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

Or more simplified way for your understanding purpose.

```
JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(json);

var result = jObject["Configurations"]["Tr984"]["Operations"].Children().Children().ToList();

foreach (JToken token in result)
{
    JObject jObject1 = token.ToObject<JObject>();

    foreach (JProperty property in jObject1.Properties())
    {
        //comboBox1.Items.Add(property.Value);  
        Console.WriteLine(property.Name + ": " + property.Value);
    }
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: @pooja, If answer help you then mark the tick on left side of answer to make it green :)